# Adding libatomic to Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I made a Spring Boot application and put it in a Docker container.
When I run it on Windows container it works fine, but when I switch it to Linux i get the following error:

> jna java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
COPY . .
ADD target/test.jar test.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/test.jar"]
```

How can I add libatomic to the Docker Image?

Comment: Are you mixing C and C++?   I don't recommend mixing them.  The C++ language allows overloading of operators and functions, which may wreak havoc when calling C language functions.  Also, classes are not portable between C and C++, expecially the accessibility and inheritance.  Remove the language tags you are not using.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am using a jna jar that I guess requires libatomic. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method) ~[jna-5.7.0.jar!/:5.7.0 (b0)]